# Interaction between "nan" data, unbounded coords, and stack plots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have noticed a strange interaction since the last update of my Miktex packages that I cannot explain. Perhaps someone knows about it here. Here is an MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
       \begin{axis}[unbounded coords=jump, stack plots=y]
          \addplot[fill=gray, draw=black] table[]{123.tsv}
          \closedcycle;
          \addplot[fill=none, draw=black] table[]{123.tsv}
          \closedcycle;
       \end{axis}
     \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

my data looks like this

```
1     nan
1.2   0.2
0.9   0.1
```

running the above produce the error:  `Undefined control sequence. [\closedcycle;]`

The error goes away if I do either of the following three things:

1. take out `unbounded coords=jump`: *nothing changes visibly, but no error*
2. take out `stack plots=y`: *plot looks obviously different*
3. take out the `nan`-line in the data: *nothing changes visibly, but no error*

I do not want to do either of these things (data and tikzpicture is supposed to be created by matlab2tikz who I cannot tell to not produce this) and the picture drawn under the errors looks good to me.

However, I have this error now (and only since the last update of my packages). Does anyone have an idea why it produces this error, why it wasn't produced before, and how to get around it?

What I tried:

- adding `\pgfplotsset{compat=x.x}`:  *does not help*
- taking away the `\closedcycle`: *produces undefined control sequence `\addplot`*

Comment: Make a bug report, pgf/tikz changed and now something is undefined ...

Comment: bug report created: https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/512/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be a bug in `pgfplots` rather than PGF, which only surfaced now due to changes in PGF, because if I simply define the undefined control sequence, it works as expected.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\makeatletter
\def\pgfplots@stacked@diff{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
       \begin{axis}[unbounded coords=jump, stack plots=y]
          \addplot[fill=gray, draw=black] table[]{123.tsv}
          \closedcycle;
          \addplot[fill=none, draw=black] table[]{123.tsv}
          \closedcycle;
       \end{axis}
     \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]